# Asp.net gridview copy items

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm working on an ASP.NET application. Main page consist of two Grids. That grid is bound to a List and its first column is a CheckBox column allowing user to select orders to work with.

When user clicks on submit button, the selected orders are copied to the second grid.

My questions:

1) What is the easiest way to get selected orders as List from grid 1?

2) Any recommendations one get selection from grid 1 in grid 2?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the GridView rows and add them to the same type of object being used to bind to the first Grid. Then Set the second grid's datasource to that object you've created and call DataBind(). Alternatively, you could use the SelectedIndexChanged event which will fire every time the Select button is clicked but after the GridView control handles the select operation.